# Multicols and enumerate

Tags: enumerate, multicol

I'm using `multicols` environment inside the `enumerate` one like this:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\begin{multicols}{2}

  \item Se o $\tri ABC$ é isósceles de base $\ov{BC}$, determine $x$.
  \begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[scale=1]{m5c4exf2}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{center}

  \vspace{.5cm}

  \item O triângulo $ABC$ é equilátero. Determine $x$ e $y$.
  \begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[scale=1]{m5c4exf3}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{center}

  \end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}
```

then I get this:
[image]

So there's a problem in the exercise number. How can I fix it?

Thanks :)

Comment: Shouldn't `multicols` be outside and `enumerate` inside?

Comment: But then all the exercises would be written in two columns and I don't wanna this. Just for some exercises.

Comment: I wonder that this works at all, apart from the wrong number there

Comment: `\begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}` is just a strange way of adding vertical space, it doesn't centre anything as the inner minipage is `\linewidth` wide so  center or flush left or right has no visible effect.

Comment: You could increase `\columnsep` just before `\begin{multicols}`, by using something like `\setlength\columnsep{30pt}`

Comment: I'm gonna try this, @GonzaloMedina, thanks!

Comment: Please post **complete** code i.e. a complete, small compilable document starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. This is almost (but not quite) infinitely more useful than mere fragments in almost (but not quite) all cases. Note that even adding a class and loading `multicol`, your code will not compile for me! And when I delete everything which doesn't work, I find your example doesn't reproduce the issue anyway - the numbers are correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `enumitem` you can get the correct numbering without nesting `multicols` inside `enumerate`. The idea is to use the `series` key provided by `enumitem` to tag the first occurrence of the `enumerate` environment. Subsequent instances then use `resume` to continue the numbering in sequence:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,multicol}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}[series=mine]
    \item first item
    \item second item
  \end{enumerate}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{enumerate}[resume*=mine]
    \item third item
    \item fourth item
  \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\begin{enumerate}[resume*=mine]
    \item fifth item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: Continuous numbering with <code>enumitem</code>]

To make clear this also solves the spacing issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,multicol}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}[series=mine]
    \item first item
    \item second item
  \end{enumerate}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{enumerate}[resume=mine]
    \item third item here is some text just to fill up the space, of course
    \item fourth item here is some text just to fill up the space, of course
  \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\begin{enumerate}[resume=mine]
    \item fifth item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: Longer items with space between]

Comment: I didn't know about it. Thank you so much for helping :)

Comment: @mvfs314 You're welcome. I rely so heavily on `enumitem` that I sometimes forget it isn't part of LaTeX itself! (And it seemed perfect for this.)